# Service fabric stateless service authorization

Tags: c#, azure, azure-service-fabric

I am trying to protect services exposed with remoting using certificate.

Service fabric does provide a mechanism to do it using **X509Credentials** class

Seems like it is trying to load the certificate from local store and cannot accept X509Certificate2 as a parameter .

Any idea how to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1):

There's good documentation about this [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-services-secure-communication#help-secure-a-service-when-youre-using-service-remoting).

- Create your service
- Add listener settings and security credentials.
- When you call methods on a secured service by using the remoting stack, use `ServiceProxyFactory`, provide `FabricTransportRemotingSettings`, with `SecurityCredentials`.

Comment: Thanks LoekD, I have referred same documentation before ,however I am looking for a mechanism to load x509Certificat2 from database instead of local cert store

Comment: Perhaps you can use a `SetupEntryPoint` to get the cert from the database and add it to the store, combined with a different X509FindType, like `FindByTimeValid`?

Comment: I think this is a very common concern , organization may not want to install certificates on local store . Microsoft need to make SecurityCredentials extensible ..what do you think ?